# What is a simple machine learning model for time series prediction that can be used in the feature engineering phase?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, svm, lstm

I need a simple model that would be fast to train and would be suitable for time series prediction that would be used mainly to generate new features. Should I use LSTM or SVM or maybe something else?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  Without knowing your data set and use case, we have no way of suggesting specific models, or even model classes.  Doing so is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The model which is suitable for your data is variable. But the simplest model in math is vanilla RNN.

There is a nice article for your reference:
http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

Comment: There are several reasons why people use LSTMs over vanilla RNN; depending on the task at hand (which wasn't specfied explicitly), it can perform significantly worse than a LSTM, or other recurrent structures (like GRUs)...